# LESS CSS problem

Tags: javascript, css, import, less

I am trying to use LESS CSS to write my CSS. I have imported the style.css and less.js file in that order.

But i am not able to generate the CSS when i write the CSS like this

```
@black: #231f20;
@brown: #241714;
@red: #cd0001;

#header #logo { width:224px; height: 75px; backgroud-color:@red;}
```

Link: http://bakasura.in/king/

Less File: http://bakasura.in/king/css/styles.less

Comment: Is this way tested and proved to have a significantly better speed? Upd. File size wise, I think you would be making a bigger difference if you eleminted spaces (like `{ ` and `; abc`) and unnecessary chars like `;` at the end of the style block.

Comment: according to my knowledge we need to use this only on development. so that you will have a better CSS at the end of it. Once u wanna move it into production u can use the generated CSS file by the LESS system and link to it.

Comment: It is when you have huge files.

Comment: i am using it for the first time by the way.

Comment: @Rich how to extract the generated CSS file on running the less ?

Comment: I've used SASS instead, which comes with a script that automatically produces a CSS file from the SCSS file. That means that the user just gets a usual CSS file, whilst you get the niceties of variables, mixins etc.

Comment: okay. will try to search else where how it can be done..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backgroud-color:@red` contains a typo.

Try `background-color:@red` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your source you import the less.js after the styles.less

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/styles.less">
<script src="js/less-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

This may or may not make any difference.

Comment: there was a typo.. that caused the error. to answer your point. they have to have the less file before the js file

Comment: fair enough @thirtydot, wasnt sure, just poster said that he had them in a different order. Looks like your answer did the trick